# list index out of range when copying csv file to list of dict

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to copy data from a csv file to a list of dict but I get a "list index out of range" error message when executing pointing to line pb_data[counter]["episode"].append(episodes). I checked the variables with print and counter is correctly set to 0.

Here is my code :

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime


pb_data = [
    {
        "episode": [],
        "title": [],
        "pubdate": []
    }
]

with open("downloads_stats.csv", "r") as f:
    counter = csv.reader(f, delimiter = "\n")
    data = list(counter)
    episodes = len(data) - 1

with open("downloads_stats.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    counter = 0
    for row in reader:
        pb_data[counter]["episode"].append(episodes)
        pb_data[counter]["title"].append(row["ï»¿Episode"])
        pb_data[counter]["pubdate"].append(datetime.strptime(row['Release Date'], '%Y-%m-%d').strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
        episodes -= 1
        counter += 1
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: If you want to convert the read csv to a list of dict, you can do it via pandas DataFrame.to_dict function. Its a two-line code. [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html). : data=pd.read_csv(filepath); data.to_dict()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `pb_data` is a list containing one dictionary, so you get an `IndexError` when counter is greater than zero (the index of the first element in the list).

Instead you need to start with an empty list, and append a new dictionary for each row in the csv, like this:

```
import csv
import datetime as dt

# Example csv data
data = """\
Episode,Release Date
Ep1,2021-01-01
Ep2,2021-01-08
Ep3,2021-01-15
"""


pb_data = []
with open("downloads_stats.csv", "r", encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # Skip headers
    next(reader)
    rows = list(reader)
    episodes = len(rows)
    for episode, date in rows:
        data = {}
        episodes -= 1
        data['episode'] = episodes
        data['title'] = episode
        data['pubdate'] = dt.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
        pb_data.append(data)

print(pb_data)
```

Output

```
[{'episode': 2, 'title': 'Ep1', 'pubdate': '01-01-2021'}, {'episode': 1, 'title': 'Ep2', 'pubdate': '08-01-2021'}, {'episode': 0, 'title': 'Ep3', 'pubdate': '15-01-2021'}]
```

The `encoding='utf-8-sig'` keyword argument to open decodes the file so that it doesn't start with "ï»¿", a byte order mark that signifies that the file is encoded with Microsoft's version of the UTF-8 text encoding.

Comment: It works great, thanks a lot I learned something new today !